# iPhone: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController won't show up properly in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to show up contacts from iPhone contacts book in UITabBarController. I came so far:

```
- (void)contacts 
{
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
// place the delegate of the picker to the controller
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

CGRect newFrame = self.tabBarController.view.frame;
newFrame.size.height = newFrame.size.height - 49;
picker.view.frame = newFrame;
[picker setAccessibilityViewIsModal:YES];
// showing the picker
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
}
```

Calling:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self contacts];
}
```

As the result I am getting this:

[image]

1. I can't see the tabs
2. My tabs style is black, but the picker is blue.
3. There's the cancel button.

How to make tabs visible, make style black and get rid of cancel button?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

After changing the method:

```
-(void)contacts
{
   ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
picker.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
// Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty], nil];
picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
// Show the picker
picker.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
CGRect newFrame = picker.view.frame;
newFrame.size.height = newFrame.size.height - 49;
picker.view.frame = newFrame;

[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:picker.view];

}
```

I've got this result:

[image]

Yes the contacts are sitting inside the tab, but now have the problems:

1. When I touch the the tableView with contacts, the contacts are disappearing at all.
2. When I switch the tabs, the contacts view doesn't go away and I can see it in all the tabs.
3. The half of UISearchbar stays hidden.

Where's the evil now?

Comment: Hi. Did you embed this view controller in your tab bar controller in storyboard? What do your table view delegate and data source methods look like?

Comment: Yes, I've embedded this UIViewController in UITabBarController in storyboard. This particular tab bar is chained to UIViewController that hasn't any UITableViews. Running on my device I can see the contacts. The only problem is that no tabs, damn cancel button and wrong style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping you figured this out by now, but it's because a modal view controller is added to the top of the active window.  That's why it goes over the top of your tab bar.  `UIViewController` also has a method `presentViewController:animated:completion:` that will probably work better for you.  You have some animation options if you specify the type for the animation using the `modalTransitionStyle` property. Good luck (if it's even still a question).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. I've solved this problem already. Your answer is right.

Answer (score 2):

You are presenting the view controller on top of the tabBarController, that is why the tabBar is hidden. Try something like:

```
UIViewController *controller = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; // Let's assume this is the desired view controller that should display the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController
[controller presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
```

Keep in mind, presenting a UIViewController (subclass) underneath a tabbar controller might result in some really strange user experience. Furthermore, you will have to set a table view bottom inset (same height as the tabBar, which is normally 49px) to the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in order to view the very last entry of the table.

ABPeoplePickerNavigationController has a navigationBar property, you can change it's tint color to (e.g.) black:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

I doubt you will be able to remove the cancel button without being rejected at the app approval process. Furthermore, there is no property of the cancel button within the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, so you will have to get the reference from e.g. scan through the navigationBar subviews.

Comment: I don't have any tableViews in this tab but uiview.

Comment: I just made it picker.navigationBarHidden=YES; anyway, it did change only the bar's color to black. the search controller and other guy are default tinted.

Comment: "I doubt you will be able to remove the cancel button without being rejected at the app approval process"... The WhatsApp and Viber they do not use cancel button. I hardly can find any use for cancel button in UITabBar app.

Comment: I doubt WhatsApp is using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. Also, I don't said it is not possible, but I think you will have to implement the PeoplePickerViewController on your own, by fetching the address book users and displaying them within your own UITableViewController.

Comment: maybe this sample can help you: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/multicontactsselector

Comment: No, this example is not about my problem.